# Click listener won't work from generated html with jsondata

Tags: jquery, json

have trouble with getting the value obtaining click listener from an element.
When i click on "tagit" it will happen nothing and dont know why!!

I have this code in my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateBuddyStat()
{
    $.getJSON('/update-buddies', function(jsonData){

     var counterjson = 0;
     var LI_list_html = '';

     $.each(jsonData, function(i,value){

      var count = counterjson++;
      var username = jsonData[i].name;
      var buddy = jsonData[i].buddyid;

      var DIV_html = username+' <div class="FunctionBuddyBox"><span class="TagBuddy" id="TagsBuddy_'+buddy+'" data-tagbuddyid="'+buddy+'">tagit</span></div>';

      LI_list_html = LI_list_html+'<li>'+DIV_html+'</li>';
     });

     $("#ShowBuddyList ul li").remove();
     $("#ShowBuddyList ul").html(LI_list_html);  
    })
}
setInterval("UpdateBuddyStat()", 3000);
</script>
```

And this is how i catch the listener:

```
$('[id^=TagsBuddy_]').click(function(){
    var buddyid = $(this).data('tagbuddyid');
    alert(buddyid);         
});
```

By this code bellow (static html) it will works fine:

```
<?php echo $value['name'] ?> <div class="FunctionBuddyBox">
<span class="TagBuddy" id="TagsBuddy_<?php echo $value['fb_id'] ?>" data-tagbuddyid="<?php echo $value['fb_id'] ?>">tagit</span>
</div>
```

Dont have any idea why! Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: you should escape any possible output data, generated by a user.
Otherwise you'll have vulnerabilities, like here: `data-tagbuddyid="'+buddy+'"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use event delegation to handle the events:

```
$('#ShowBuddyList').on('click', '[id^=TagsBuddy_]', function() {
    var buddyid = $(this).data('tagbuddyid');
    alert(buddyid);         
});
```

Also, don't use strings with `setInterval`:

```
setInterval("UpdateBuddyStat()", 3000);
```

Pass the function:

```
setInterval(UpdateBuddyStat, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need event delegation:

```
$("#ShowBuddyList").on('click', '[id^=TagsBuddy_]', function(){
    var buddyid = $(this).data('tagbuddyid');
    alert(buddyid);         
});
```

delegate to the closest parent which is available in the dom or use `document` instead.

Answer (score 3):

As you are loading HTML content dynamically you have to use `.on()` as event listener. Try

```
$('#ShowBuddyList ul').on('click', '[id^=TagsBuddy_]', function(){
    var buddyid = $(this).data('tagbuddyid');
    alert(buddyid);         
});
```

Comment: Danke dir, war sehr hilfreich für mich!

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$('[id^=TagsBuddy_]').click(function(){
    var buddyid = $(this).data('tagbuddyid');
    alert(buddyid);         
});
```

to

```
$('#ShowBuddyList').on('click','[id^=TagsBuddy_]',(function(){
    var buddyid = $(this).data('tagbuddyid');
    alert(buddyid);         
});
```

the `click()` method only works on elements added during the page load - you need to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added content. Note that the selector for the `on()` method needs to be present on document load and must be a parent element of the selector used inside the `on()` method (`'[id^=TagsBuddy_]'` in this example)